# ASP.NET Core 3.1 add endpoint for ashx files

Tags: angular, captcha, asp.net-core-3.1

I use [Captcha](https://captcha.com) in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 application, captcha library generate **ashx** file to show image independently.

I have to define special route for that because my main project is contain SPA project (existed ClientApp folder) and when request executed for this route "http://localhost:5000/captcha.ashx" this route ignored and navigated to defined routes in angular project then finnaly show 404.

How can I define this route?

In my Startup file

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
       endpoints.MapControllers();

       endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

       endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                name: "areas", "areas",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


       endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notification");
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
       spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
       if (env.IsDevelopment())
       {
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
       }
 });
```